# Why did remix v0.33.0 prompt me to use coinbase unless I shortened the url? Then it allowed generic injected provider

Tags: remix, metamask

This is surprising to find out. I googled and clicked the remix.ethereum.org link. I got on remix to do a quick deployment however it prompted me to use coinbase instead of a generic injected provider. If I shrunk down the url, I could use metamask. Super strange.

https://remix.ethereum.org/#lang=en&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.18+commit.87f61d96.js

vs

https://remix.ethereum.org/

I am curious if anyone else ran into this.